# Index issue - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to parse values from a JSON data file to a Javascript function. The JSON data file gets it's values from a database and looks like this :

```
[
{
    "speeds": "5.0",
    "rates": "130",
    "duration": "3"
},
{
    "speeds": "5.5",
    "rates": "136",
    "duration": "6"
},
{
    "speeds": "6.0",
    "rates": "142",
    "duration": "9"
},
{
    "speeds": "6.5",
    "rates": "148",
    "duration": "12"
},
{
    "speeds": "7.0",
    "rates": "149",
    "duration": "15"
},
{
    "speeds": "7.5",
    "rates": "159",
    "duration": "18"
}
]
```

The javascript code is this :

```
function getMaxDelta(array) {
          return array[array.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
              return aa[r + 1] - aa[r] < aa[i + 1] - a ? i : r;
          }, 0)];
      }

      var hRate = []        
      $.each(caldata, function(i, obj) {
          hRate.push([parseInt(obj.rates)]);
          });

      console.log([hRate].map(getMaxDelta));
    }
```

The console outputs : Array [ Array[1] ]. The properties of the output show Array [1], 0:149, length:1.

I'm trying to achieve this : Array [149]

I think the problem is related to indexing, but can't figure out. Can anyone point me in the right direction - much appreciated

Comment: Change `console.log([hRate].map(getMaxDelta))` to `console.log(getMaxDelta(hRate))`, it should work.

Comment: Thanks - it works!!! - But the console is now showing 'a' (from the getMaxDelta function) is undefined??? - Still works though?

Comment: If you want to notify a user who has commented on your question (or answer) you need to include that user's name -- e.g. @PedroNascimento